# Displaying Default language after orientation changed

Tags: android

In my App home pager, user can select language. if he select Spanish and login after if orientation changes at that time default English language coming.

Comment: set your Locale as a Default to Spanish

Comment: after orientation changes what ever language selected before that one only i want

Comment: let me see your code first

Comment: Locale loc = new Locale("es"); 
              Locale.setDefault(loc);
              restartFirstActivity();
            //tv.setText(getResources().getString(R.id.hello_world));
                Configuration config = new Configuration();
                 config.locale = loc; 
                 getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config, getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());

Comment: add android:configChanges="locale" in your activity in manifest.xml

Answer (score 0):

Add below code in AndroidManifest.xml actvity tag.

`android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
String lang = "es"; //set default to Spanish
    Resources res = context.getResources();
        // Change locale settings in the app.
        DisplayMetrics dm = res.getDisplayMetrics();
        android.content.res.Configuration conf = res.getConfiguration();
        conf.locale = new Locale(lang);
        res.updateConfiguration(conf, dm);
```

Now, after user changes the language, I would save the language to `sharedPrefs`, and in the `onCreate` I would load that Locale from the `sharedPrefs` and use it in the method above.
That way the setting will not get lost.